# How can I split a list of strings based on quantity and name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I split a list of strings based on quantity and name?

For example if I have string str that looks like the following:

```
5 apples
7x pine apples
10 oranges
14x corn on the cob
apple pie
```

I could do,

```
var list = str.split(/\r?\n/);
```

So now I have each line in an array list but now I still need to get the quantity and name from each element in the list.

For list[0] which is '5 apples' I could do,

```
var breakdown = list[0].split(' ');
```

For list[1] I'd have to remove the 'x' from '7x' and it would incorrectly be split into 3 rather than just the quantity and name , etc.

For 'apple pie' the quantity should be 1.

The expected result is always,

```
breakdown[0]: quantity
breakdown[1]: name
```

How can I get the quantity and name regardless of how it's entered?

Comment: How about apple pie?

Comment: parseInt is extremely forgiving. parseInt("14x corn on the cob") returns the integer 14

Comment: yep, you'll need to do something different  for that one  :)

Comment: I added expected result to clarify. I'd expect an array with just an integer quantity and name.

Comment: parseInt("apple pie") returns Nan. Check for Nan and return 0.


`function getQuantity(str) {
    var val = parseInt(str);
    return val == NaN ? 0 : val;
}`

Comment: My bad, you're actually going to have to use something other than `split()` since it would break the names that have spaces in them. `match()` might be the best fit for your use case.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm It's cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regex on each line would do it. This follows with a second `.map()` to convert the numeric (or empty) string to a number.

```js
var data = `5 apples
7x pine apples
10 oranges

14x corn on the cob
apple pie`;

var result = data.split(/\s*?(?:\r?\n)+\s*/g).map(s =>
  /^(?:(\d+)x?\s+)?(.+)$/.exec(s).slice(1)
).map(([q, d]) => [+q || 1, d]);

console.log(result);
```

---

It could actually be done with just a regex too, if you include the `m` modifier.

```js
var data = `5 apples
7x pine apples
10 oranges

14x corn on the cob
apple pie`;

var re = /^(?:(\d+)x?\s+)?(.+)$/gm;
var m;
var result = [];

while((m = re.exec(data))) {
  result.push([+m[1] || 1, m[2]]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is really close but apple pie is 0?

Comment: @rotaercz: Oops, I forgot the requirement. I'll change it.

Comment: This is really good. Just one more thing for completionism. It doesn't seem to be able to handle empty lines?

Comment: You're a rock star! ;)

Comment: instead of `? ?` you are encouraged to use `?\s?`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Yes that's a good idea to handle other space characters.

Comment: @rotaercz: Glad it helped!

Comment: Is just regex faster?

Comment: Not sure. Probably wouldn't worry about it unless you have very long lists.

Comment: Yeah, my lists should never exceed 200 lines for a single list. I'll just use the shorter one for smaller file size.

Comment: I tweaked the `.split()` regex to include space before and after the line break, and the main regex so that the `x` and space is only counted if it comes after the digits.

Comment: They're both so short, I'll go try a speed test and report back.

Comment: I'll make one more change. The `x` would now seem to be captured. Not sure why it's actually working, but I'll change it anyway.

Comment: Sounds good. That'll be interesting. I'm betting on the regex only version

Comment: We have a winner. The regex version is about 3 times faster. It's unquestionably faster.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't working. It was giving `NaN`, so the `|| 1` was substituted. Fixed now.

Comment: @rotaercz: Good to know. Figured it must be doing less work overall.

Comment: The latest regex version you put up is actually even faster. It's a little over 3 times faster. Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, you're welcome. Made one more change, but it doesn't change the output. Just gave the regex one more tweak. Best of luck!

Comment: It's 4 times faster! XD

Comment: Wow, didn't think that simplification would make that much difference. Thanks for the reports.